# Jquery datepicker works only after a page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm writing a program where there is a table to be created when ever there id a date change. But the problem here, first the table gets created on selecting date, But when i start changing the date the table doesn't get created, and there are no errors in the console. Below are my codes.

**table.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jbPivot.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jbPivot.css">


</head>
<body>
    <marquee>
        <h1>This is an example of ajax</h1>
    </marquee>

    <p>
        Date: <input type="text" id="startDatePicker">
    </p>
    <p>
        Date: <input type="text" id="endDatePicker">
    </p>
    <span id="somediv"> <span id="err">Select Correct Dates</span>
    </span>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tableGenerator.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**tableGenerator.js**

```
var startDate = $("#startDatePicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
    onClose : function(selectedDate) {
        $("#endDatePicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
var endDate = $("#endDatePicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
    onClose : function(selectedDate) {
        $("#startDatePicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
$(document).on('change', '#startDatePicker,#endDatePicker', function() {
    $('#somediv > table').remove();
    $.getJSON('Controller', {
        'startDate' : startDate.val(),
        'endDate' : endDate.val()
    }, function(searchList) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(searchList));
        if (searchList.length < 1) {
            $('#err').show();
            $('#err').text("No Records found in Specified Dates");
        } else {
            $("#somediv").jbPivot({
                fields : {
                    caseOwner : {
                        field : 'caseOwner',
                        sort : "asc",
                        showAll : true,
                        agregateType : "distinct"
                    },
                    finalStatus : {
                        field : 'finalStatus',
                        sort : "asc",
                        showAll : false,
                        agregateType : "distinct"
                    },
                    status : {
                        field : 'status',
                        sort : "asc",
                        showAll : false,
                        agregateType : "distinct"
                    },
                    Count : {
                        agregateType : "count",
                        groupType : "none"
                    },
                },
                xfields : [ "caseOwner" ],
                yfields : [ "finalStatus" ],
                statfields : [ "status" ],
                zfields : [ "Count" ],
                data : searchList
            });

        }

    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.bean.UserBean;

import com.dao.DataDao;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

@WebServlet("/Controller")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            /* Date Start */
            String startDateStr = request.getParameter("startDate");
            String endDateStr = request.getParameter("endDate");
            System.out.println("Start date got is " + startDateStr + " and end date is " + endDateStr);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            SimpleDateFormat print = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date startParsedDate = null, endParsedDate = null;
            String startDate = null, endDate = null;
            if (startDateStr != null && !startDateStr.equals("")) {
                startParsedDate = sdf.parse(startDateStr);
                startDate = print.format(startParsedDate);
            }
            if (endDateStr != null && !endDateStr.equals("")) {
                endParsedDate = sdf.parse(endDateStr);
                endDate = print.format(endParsedDate);
            }

            System.out.println(startDate + " value and " + endDate);
            /* Date End */
            DataDao dataDao = new DataDao();
            ArrayList<UserBean> list = dataDao.getFrameWork(startDate, endDate);
            String searchList = new Gson().toJson(list);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(searchList);
            System.out.println("servlet Done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage() + " servlet Errotr");
        }
    }
}
```

**DataDAO.java**

```
package com.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.bean.UserBean;

public class DataDao {
    private Connection connection;

    public DataDao() throws Exception {
        connection = DBUtility.getConnection();
    }

    public ArrayList<UserBean> getFrameWork(String startDate, String endDate) throws SQLException {
        String startDateFromController = startDate;
        String endDateFromController = endDate;
        System.out.println("DAO VAlues are " + startDateFromController + " and " + endDateFromController);
        ArrayList<UserBean> list = new ArrayList<UserBean>();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            String query;

            if (!(startDateFromController == null) && endDateFromController == null) {
                System.out.println("first block imvoked");
                query = "select * from StatusTable where convert(date, [Start Time]) >= ?";
                ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                ps.setString(1, startDateFromController);
            } else if (startDateFromController == null && !(endDateFromController == null)) {
                System.out.println("end date is " + endDateFromController);
                System.out.println("second");
                query = "select * from StatusTable where convert(date, [Start Time]) <= ?";
                ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                ps.setString(1, endDateFromController);
            } else if (startDateFromController == null && endDateFromController == null) {
                System.out.println("Thuird block");
                query = "select * from StatusTable where [Start Time] Is NOT NULL";
                ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Forth block");
                query = "select * from StatusTable where convert(date, [Start Time]) between ? and ?";
                ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                ps.setString(1, startDate);
                ps.setString(2, endDate);
            }
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("No records found");
            } else {
                do {
                    UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
                    userBean.setCaseNumber(rs.getString("Case Number"));
                    userBean.setCaseOwner(rs.getString("Case Owner"));
                    userBean.setStatus(rs.getString("Status"));
                    userBean.setIssue(rs.getString("Issue"));
                    userBean.setReason(rs.getString("Reason"));
                    userBean.setDateOpened(rs.getString("Date/Time Opened"));
                    userBean.setAge(rs.getInt("Age"));
                    userBean.setFinalStatus(rs.getString("Final Status"));
                    list.add(userBean);
                } while (rs.next());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e + " DAO Error");
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

please let me know how can i do this. I should get the data without refreshing the page. i.e. As soon as i change the date, the changes should be reflecting.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Arkantos, Thanks for the quick edit.

Comment: I think you can remove your `DBUtility` code. Coming to your issue, did you check the response for the AJAX call that you're making when you change the date ? Open Dev Tools (F12) and see the network tab and see if the response is coming as expected

Comment: Yes I did, it is the same json response. I mean there is no error or such thing, json data is displayed in the log.

Comment: Hi @Arkantos, removed that class. please let me know howcan I fix this. Thanks

Comment: I don't see any issues other than the fact that you're always applying the pivot widget every time you get the JSON response instead of resetting your table and inserting records again. Did you check if the response from your ajax call is different each time you change your date ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see in your code is that you're always trying to initialize the pivot table widget on your `somediv` element. I think pivot table widget will not update the table if you try to initialize the widget on the same element again and again with different data. According to the docs [here](https://github.com/uniclau/jbPivot), if you want to replace the table data, you should get a reference to the pivot data object and call `insertRecords()` with your new list.

```
 var $data = $("#pivot1").data('jbPivot');
 $data.reset();
 $data.insertRecords([--your-new--array--]);
```

Here's a sample [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqqYrG) in action.

Comment: Hi Arkantos, sorry for the delayed reply, Yes the data in console is getting updated each time i select a date